# 24 Math Game - Random number generator and solver in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you create a number generator for the Game 24 in Javascript?
Random number generator should only generate numbers that can solve for 24. Only generate numbers that can solve problem.

Rules of the game:

You get 4 numbers. You need to make 24. You can +,x,- and % those numbers to get 24.

Example: 4, 2, 8, 1

((4-2) + 1) x 8 = 24

The random number generator should give you 4 numbers that will make up 24. You must not get any numbers that will not make 24, for example 1,1,1 and 2.

I only want to use whole numbers.

I would like to change the game a bit. Instead of always using 24, I might like to use a different number, such as 12 for beginners and 55 for advanced players, etc.

I am a beginner and the point of this is to learn JavaScript. Any explanation would be great.

Comment: `parseInt(Math.random() * 24)` should give you whole numbers from 0 to 23

Comment: what is the condition to obtain the given numbers ?

Comment: do you just want the random numbers, or the solver?

Comment: It should not generate any numbers, that wont make 24. In away it is also a solver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fiddle shows a method for getting a series of numbers that can somehow add-up to the given number:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e37nfjn/)

This is an easy way to get "random" numbers because i simply sum my random operations and insert one controlled operation in the end to make sure it can produce the wanted target.

I'll dump the source code below for those of you who don't wish to follow the link:

```
console.clear();
function getNumberGame(target, length) {
    console.clear();
    var dataset = [];
    var methods = {
        'add' : function (a, b) {
            return (a + b);
        },
        'subtract' : function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },
        'multiply' : function (a, b) {
            if (a !== 0 && b !== 0 && a < Infinity && b < Infinity) {
                return Math.round(a * b);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        'divide' : function (a, b) {
            if (a !== 0 && b !== 0 && a < Infinity && b < Infinity) {
                return Math.round(a / b);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        var obj = {
            value : Math.round(Math.random() * target) + 1,
            method : Object.keys(methods)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(methods).length)]
        };
        dataset.push(obj);
    }
    delete dataset[0].method;
    var data = dataset[0].value * 1;
    console.log('Start with ' + data);
    for (var i = 1; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        data = methods[dataset[i].method](data, dataset[i].value);
        console.log(dataset[i].method + " " + dataset[i].value + " to get " + data);
    }
    if (data > target) {
        dataset.push({
            value : Math.round(Math.abs(data - target)),
            method : 'subtract'
        });
        console.log("subtract " + dataset[dataset.length - 1].value + " to get " + target);
    } else if (data < target) {
        dataset.push({
            value : Math.round(Math.abs(data - target)),
            method : 'add'
        });
        console.log("add " + dataset[dataset.length - 1].value + " to get " + target);
    }
    var returnArray = [];
    while (dataset.length > 0) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataset.length);
        returnArray.push(dataset[i].value);
        dataset.splice(i, 1);
    }
    console.log(returnArray);
    alert("Make \"" + target + "\" by combining these " + length + ":\n" + returnArray.join(', '));
    return returnArray;
}

getNumberGame(parseInt(prompt("Target number", 24)), parseInt(prompt("Steps", 4)));
```

**EDIT 1**

Note that there is no check for `Infinity` or `0` in the `multiply` and `divide` functions which can result in some strange behavior. My code simply returns `0` (by returning `false`) in such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Original text at the bottom.

Ok, so I did it, I'm not exactly proud of how brute the code is and I'm sure it can be made more efficient in about a thousand places, but it works.

```
//[A,B,C,D]

var skillLevel = 24;
numbers = [];
for (i=0;i<=3;i++){
    numbers[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * skillLevel) + 1);
}
function permutateOperations(numberArray){//This function, given an array of the form [A,B,C,D] where ABCD are numbers, places operations [+,-,*,%] between the numbers in the array
var possibilities = [];
var splicednumbers = numberArray.slice();
var operations = ['+','-','*','%'];
    for (var j=0;j<=3;j++){//[A,j,B,k,C,m,D]
        for(k=0;k<=3;k++){
            for(m=0;m<=3;m++){
                splicednumbers.splice(3,0,operations[m]);
                splicednumbers.splice(2,0,operations[k]);
                splicednumbers.splice(1,0,operations[j]);
                possibilities.push(splicednumbers);
                splicednumbers=numberArray.slice();
            }
        }
    }
    return possibilities;
}

function permutateNumbers(numberArray){//This function, given an array of the form [A,B,C,D], returns an array of arrays that have all the possible orderings
var possibility = [];
var possibilities = [];
var remainingArray=[];
var splicednumbers = numberArray.slice();
for (var i=0;i<=3;i++){
    threeRemain = splicednumbers.slice();//[A,B,C,D]
    possibility[0]=splicednumbers.splice(i,1)[0]; 
    for(var j=0;j<=2;j++){
        twoRemain=splicednumbers.slice();//[A,B,C]
        possibility[1]=splicednumbers.splice(j,1)[0]; 
        for(var k=0;k<=1;k++){
            oneRemain = splicednumbers.slice(); //[A,B]
            possibility[2]=splicednumbers.splice(k,1)[0];
            for(var m=0;m<=0;m++){
                possibility[3]=splicednumbers.splice(m,1)[0]; //[A]
                possibilities.push(possibility.slice());
            }
            splicednumbers=oneRemain.slice();
        }
        splicednumbers=twoRemain.slice();
    }
splicednumbers=threeRemain.slice();
}
return possibilities;
}

function permutateParenthesis(operationArray){//I AM SORRY THIS IS AWFUL BUT I COULDN'T THINK OF ANYTHING ELSE
//Given an array like [A,&,B,&,C,&,D], where ABCD are numbers and & is any operation, returns the 5 possible arrays that result from having parenthesis in different positions within it.
    saved = operationArray.slice();
    //[A,&,B,&,C,&,D]
    permutations = [];
    //First option
    operationArray.splice(0,0,"(");
    operationArray.splice(4,0,")");
    permutations.push(operationArray.slice());
    operationArray = saved.slice();
    //Second option
    operationArray.splice(0,0,"(");
    operationArray.splice(3,0,")");
    operationArray.splice(4,0,"(");
    operationArray.splice(10,0,")");
    permutations.push(operationArray.slice());
    operationArray = saved.slice();
    //Third option
    operationArray.splice(0,0,"(");
    operationArray.splice(6,0,")");
    permutations.push(operationArray.slice());
    operationArray = saved.slice();
    //Fourth option
    operationArray.splice(2,0,"(");
    operationArray.splice(7,0,")");
    permutations.push(operationArray.slice());
    operationArray = saved.slice();
    //Fifth option
    operationArray.splice(4,0,"(");
    operationArray.splice(8,0,")");
    permutations.push(operationArray.slice());
    operationArray = saved.slice();

    return permutations;
}
finalnumbers = permutateNumbers(numbers);
operationNumbers = [];
for (i=0;i<finalnumbers.length;i++){
    operationNumbers.push(permutateOperations(finalnumbers[i]));
}
parenthesisNumbers=[];
//Showtime
for (var j=0;j<operationNumbers.length;j++){
    for (var k=0;k<operationNumbers[j].length;k++){
        parenthesisNumbers.push(permutateParenthesis(operationNumbers[j][k]));
           if (eval(operationNumbers[j][k].join(""))===24){//get a string with the finished combination, eval it to perform the operation, see if it is 24
           console.log(operationNumbers[j][k].join("") + " Is valid");
           }
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL:

I think most people here are missing the problem.

The issue here is not generating random numbers below 24 (which is not even something you need to do, given the numbers [50,6,6,2] you can do 6 * 2 * (50%6) = 24, I guess you do need an upper limit though)

The issue here is, after getting 4 numbers, checking out wether or not they can get to be 24 given any combination of operations, and that is far more complex.

You have 4 operations [+,-,*,%] and 4 numbers [A,B,C,D], for starters you would have to check every combination of these two sets, the first one can repeat (solution might be [+,+,+,+]) and the second can't (even though numbers might repeat you have a limited amount of each number) so that means performing 4*4*4 (every combination of [+,-,*,%]) checks for each one of the possible combinations of [A,B,C,D], 4*3*2*1, which adds to 1536 checks before trying to make it efficient in any way.

THEN you have to start taking parenthesis into account which multiplies the posisbilities some more.

I applaud the initiative and I think it's an interesting problem, but im going to agree with libik here that if all you want is learn javascript there are simpler things to do.

If you choose to move forward then I hope I've pointed you to the right direction and I'll be happy to help if I can, I honestly might try to solve it myself since I think it's an interesting problem.

Comment: I have my exam soon. I will concentrate on easier Javascript problems. But i really like this problem and will come back to it definitely. To be honest i didn't think it would be that difficult. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you do decide to try and solve it, i want to be the first to know. I will take a look at this problem after my exam.

Answer (score 0):

use this to generate random numbers between 1 and current skillLevel:

```
var skillLevel = getCurrentSkillLevel(); // get skill level in any way you seem appropriate.

function getRandomInt(skillLevel) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * skillLevel) + 1;
}
```

where skillLevel is 24, 55 or whatever.

Comment: getRandomInt(1, skillLevel)? SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Comment: Sounds like your completing the OPs homework... why give them the answer? Why not help them come to it on their own?

Comment: `getCurrentSkillLevel()` is called, function is named `getRandomInt`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That code alone is obviously not enough to complete OPs homework, it points him in the right direction though

Comment: @Icepickle No, the getCurrentSkillLevel is just a dummy code for a function to get the current skill level, which in turn is used to generate a random number

Comment: It is not homework. I am studying for the Microsoft exam 70-480. Just doing javascript exercises

Answer (score 0):

```
You must not get any numbers that will not make 24.
```

This sentence actually means you have to implement solver, which is quite difficult. The common approach is to try every possible combination and for that the [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) is often used.

The possibility of writing brackets makes this alghoritm very difficult to implement, but it can also be a nice challenge. I would recommend to start with  [SUDOKU solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms), which is generally easy to implement and nice looking backtracking alghoritm :

Comment: Yes, that is what i was after. I thought there might be an easy way of doing this without backtracking. Maybe something i didn't see. Thanks i will take a look at the SUDOKU solver